# Wikipedia friction example

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, friction

I am trying to work my way through this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel#Mechanics_and_function) example and I was hoping somebody could help me answer a couple of questions.

> If a 100 kg object is dragged for 10 m along a surface with the coefficient of friction μ = 0.5, the normal force is 981 N and the work done (required energy) is (work=force x distance) 981 × 0.5 × 10 = 4905 joules.

> Now give the object 4 wheels. The normal force between the 4 wheels and axles is the same (in total) 981 N. Assume, for wood, μ = 0.25, and say the wheel diameter is 1000 mm and axle diameter is 50 mm. So while the object still moves 10 m the sliding frictional surfaces only slide over each other a distance of 0.5 m. The work done is 981 × 0.25 × 0.5 = 123 joules; the work done has reduced to 1/40 of that of dragging.

a. The first part is ignoring static friction. How would I calculate the work of this? Meaning, what would be the distance to use if I knew the static coefficient of friction? Or is it negligible?

b. In the second part, why is the sliding distance only 0.5m?

c. What is the work done simply lifting the block, walking 10m and lowering the block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Static friction isn't relevant to a work calculation, as no work is done when the object isn't moving.

b) The distance moved by a wheel turning when turning an angle $\theta$ radians is $r \theta$, where $r$ is the wheel radius. To move ten meters, we must therefore have $r \theta = 10$ m. However the friction now occurs between the wheel and the axle; the turning angle is here the same (geometric contraint), but as the radius is only $r_\mathrm{axle} = 50 \text{ mm} = r/20$, the "sliding distance" is only $r_\mathrm{axle} \theta = r \theta/20 = 0.5$ m.

c) By "walling 10 m" do you mean moving it 10 m to the side while in the air? In that case, the total work done is zero.
Any work done in lifting the block will be regained upon lowering it, and similarly any work done to accelerate the block sideways will be regained upon deceleration in the other end.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jakob KS. Very clear

Comment: Can I ask you a follow up question? How would your answer change if I wanted to calculate the energy required to a) drag the block, b) drag the block on wheels and c) lift the block?

Comment: @AdrienHingert it is clear you did not understand the answer you just received. Please think through.

Comment: Work is energy, so the energy required is precisely the work - i.e. the question you are asking now is the same as the one before!
Of course if you wanted to lift the block and then set it down, you would *temporarily* require an energy $E = mgh$ to lift it, but you would regain all of that energy upon setting the block back down. That is why the total work is zero.